# Referencing list in Excel Filter function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My real world example is more complicated but have created the below example to show the problem I am trying to overcome

[image: Excel spreadsheet]

So I have a list of names in A1:A10 and another list of names in B1:B3 I need to use the =Filter function to create a list of names excluding the names in B1:B3.

I am able to get around in ths example with the formula `=FILTER(A1:A10,(A1:A10<>B1)*(A1:A10<>B2)*(A1:A10<>B3))` however this would be extremly impratical to implement. Am basically looking for somthing that would acomplish A1:10<>B1:B3

Any help would be apperciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an inner `MATCH` with `NOT` and `ISNUMBER`:

```
=FILTER(A1:A10,NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1:A10,B1:B3,0))))
```

[image]